# How to use external C++ libraries with cmake on macOS?

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, homebrew

I'm trying to find the most convenient way of installing C++ libraries on macOS by using brew. It's my first approach to understand cmake with CLion.

I would like to use C++ library `osmium` https://github.com/osmcode/libosmium:

`$ brew install libosmium`

`$ brew list libosmium
/usr/local/Cellar/libosmium/2.15.4/include/osmium/ (198 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/libosmium/2.15.4/include/gdalcpp.hpp
/usr/local/Cellar/libosmium/2.15.4/libexec/include/ (12 files)`

`$ brew unlink libosmium --dry-run | xargs ls -l
/usr/local/include/gdalcpp.hpp -> ../Cellar/libosmium/2.15.4/include/gdalcpp.hpp
/usr/local/include/osmium -> ../Cellar/libosmium/2.15.4/include/osmium`

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21685809/get-cmake-and-home-brew-to-work-together) I tried to add paths:

```
find_library(LZMA_LIBRARY lzma)
message("lzma: ${LZMA_LIBRARY}")

list(APPEND CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH /usr/local/include)
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /usr/local/include)
list(APPEND CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/include)

find_library(OSMIUM_LIBRARY_LIB libosmium)
find_library(OSMIUM_LIBRARY osmium)

message("osmium: ${OSMIUM_LIBRARY}")
message("osmium_lib: ${OSMIUM_LIBRARY_LIB}")
```

Output:

```
lzma: /usr/local/lib/liblzma.dylib
osmium: OSMIUM_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
osmium_lib: OSMIUM_LIBRARY_LIB-NOTFOUND
```

Then I played around with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58844585/use-qwt-installed-via-brew-in-cmake):

```
if(APPLE)
    set(CMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK ONLY)
    message(APPLE)
    find_library(OSM
            NAMES osmium libosmium
            HINTS /usr/local/include
            REQUIRED)
    message("OSM: ${OSM}")
    if(OSM)
        include_directories(${OSM}/Headers)
        link_libraries(${OSM})
        message("OSM found: ${OSM}")
    endif()
endif()
```

Output:

```
APPLE
OSM: OSM-NOTFOUND
```

To make everything clear [this is the code](https://github.com/osmcode/libosmium/blob/master/examples/osmium_read.cpp) which I'm trying to execute and this is the error:

```
main.cpp:5:10: fatal error: 'osmium/io/any_input.hpp' file not found
#include <osmium/io/any_input.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Maybe there is a better way to integrate external libraries C++. I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: From the project's [README](https://github.com/osmcode/libosmium/blob/master/README.md): "Osmium is a **header-only** library, so there is nothing to build for the library itself.". So `find_library` is not needed.

Comment: @Tsyvarev So you are saying `find_library` is building under the hood by using cmake files? However it would mean that my project should be able to find the library installed by brew itself but is not. Does not matter if I modify `CMakeList.txt` or not, the error which is at the end of the question appears anyway.

Comment: Directory `/usr/local/include` should be automatically used as include directory.  If not sure, you may always explicitely add this directory: `include_directories("/usr/local/include")`.Please, show (add to the question post) **exact** `CMakeList.txt` file which you use for building the example and **exact** error message it produces.

Comment: `include_directories("/usr/local/include")` helped. I didn't know that this command has to be used. Thank you for your help!